# `Extra argument 'data' in call` in Firestore, with a model usage

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been having this problem for a long time now. This program is able to compile sometimes and the error message goes away but, sometimes it will fail to compile.
**The other question with a similar name does not give an answer.**

Here's my code:
[image: code]
If you were to refer to the docs, you will see that this is exactly how they want us to make the call.

Some people have suggested that this is a problem with Xcode, although this is probably bogus. I do not know how to fix this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please do not show pictures of code.  On Stack Overflow, It's better to copy the code into the question so it's easier to read and search.  Any errors can also be copied and described in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the use of `throws` and `throw error`. From the docs

> Only throwing functions can propagate errors. Any errors thrown inside
>   a nonthrowing function must be handled inside the function.

Kinda generically speaking, while the addUser function throws, the code inside the addDocument does NOT throw and therefore there's a disconnect between the throwing function and non-throwing one.

I am not sure why you are throwing here at all as Firebase has it's own error error notification so if there's an error resulting from the Firebase call, it will trigger the error parameter to not be nil and it can be handled accordingly.

You probably want to use

```
print("Error writing document: \(error.localizedDescription)")
```

instead of

```
print("Error writing document: \(error)")
```

as well.

Comment: somehow this worked... I only wonder why it gave me such a interesting error and not about my `throw`??